# How to seamlessly rate in Photo Mechanic but also edit in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, xmp, photo-mechanic

I have been using Photo Mechanic to cull my images before I import to Lightroom because Photo Mechanic is considerably faster for this step. Where I run into an issue is when I already have the images imported to LR and I want to cull using PM. I've always set LR to Automatically write changes to XMP, so I have the XMP sidecar files already.

In PM I set "When reading IPTC/XMP: For RAW Read XMP sidecar file first" *see below*.

The issue is that once I make a rating change in PM, I get the following message in LR:

> The metadata for this photo has been changed by another application.
>   Should Lightroom import settings from disk or overwrite disk settings
>   with those from the catalog?

I can click "Overwrite" each time, but it is a pain because I have to select all images that were changed to confirm the overwrite. Is there a way to default to this or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Confirmation message in LightRoom 5:
[image]

XMP Preferences in Photo Mechanic 4.6.7:
[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, are you choosing "overwrite" because you want LR to overwrite (discard) the changes you just made in PM? http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2013/09/how-lightroom-works-with-metadata-from-other-applications.html

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to import using PhotoMechanic, do your cull there, then place your selects into a folder that Lightroom watches for import into Lightroom (and creation of XMP, etc., post-cull). You can have Lr move rather than copy your selects, which will spare you the extra file write (provided you're not paranoid, of course - if the rename is to risky, you can always maintain copy on import). The stars you assign in PM will be written to the RAW file rather than to a sidecar, of course, and will be recognised by Lr on import. Again, that's touching the RAW file, which you may or may not consider to be too risky. If you want to maintain *all* changes in XMP, never touching the RAW file, then PM isn't the tool you want, no matter how performant it is.